# error in rspec but works fine in development (can't mass-assign protected attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I recently started using rspec and factory_girl and I'm working on a basic control spec for my create action in my projects controller.

So I have this as a before filter:

```
before :each do
  @project = FactoryGirl.create(:project)
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, first_name: "Jim", last_name: "Smith", username: "jsmith")
  session[:user_id] = @user.id # this maintains the session for the user created in the previous linew
end
```

My project expects to have a user associated with it.

So in the create spec, I have this:

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  attribute_merge = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:project).merge(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user))

  context "with valid attributes" do
    it "creates a new project" do
      expect{ 
        post :create, project: attribute_merge 
        }.to change(Project,:count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

So what I'm trying to do is pass the project attributes hash along with the user attributes hash because a project requires at least one user in order to be created.  Now, the error I get is:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error:
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: first_name, last_name....
```

I should add that my create action works perfectly in development and I do have `attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :username,...` in my user.rb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing because your passing the actual attributes for the user to the project, instead of just a reference to the user.

Try

```
post :create, project: FactoryGirl.build(:project, user: user).attributes
```